# Ansible on Windows: How to change Registry ownership

Tags: ansible, windows-server-2012-r2

Ansible Version: ansible 2.9.2
I am trying to run below the playbook on Windows Server 2012 R2, which has WINRM configured.
I am able to run win_acl and win_owner modules on the directory, however, I am facing issues while changing **Registry**() ownership using Ansible.
Note: I am able to change the same manually by RDP into the server as mentioned in this article
https://github.com/jenkinsci/windows-slaves-plugin/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.adoc#windows-server-2012-64bit

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: Grant Ownership to Administrator user on the registry
    win_acl:
      path: HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\72C24DD5-D70A-438B-8A42-98424B88AFB8
      user: Administrators
      rights: TakeOwnership
      type: allow
      state: present
      inherit: ContainerInherit
      propagation: 'None'
```

```
    Error: {"changed": false, "msg": "an exception occurred when adding the specified rule - Requested registry access is not allowed."}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to do something similar with pure ansible. So i used a external tool called setacl.exe https://helgeklein.com/download/#setacl

The following example is way to extreme to be used in production. But it will show the options u have

```
    - name: Copy setacl.exe to system32
      win_copy:
        src: files/setacl.exe
        dest: C:\windows\system32\setacl.exe
    - name: Change the owner for a part of the registry
      tags: setacl
      raw: setacl.exe -on "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Enum" -ot reg -rec yes -actn setowner -ownr "n:Administrator"
    - name: Add administrator to reg
      tags: setacl
      raw: setacl.exe -on "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Enum" -ot reg -rec yes -actn ace -ace "n:Adminiistrator;p:full"
```